# Add class to main-menu ul without using a module in Drupal 7

Tags: css, drupal-theming

I'm trying to get my theme to add CSS class names to the 'ul' elements in the main-menu in Drupal 7.

HTML mock-up code:

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Resources</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
        </ul>

</ul>
```

As you can see, the "first level" ul has a class name of "topnav", the following nested ul has a class name of "subnav". I'm hooking up a jQuery drop down menu and want to apply it without the use of modules. Yes, I've tried the "Menu Attributes" module but that doesn't work here.

I've been searching all day and cannot seem to find a complete solution. I know about superfish / and other themes that come with sf, but I'm wanting my own solution.

**Edit:** 
Ok, I've gotten further.  I have a menu with subs on which jquery is initially hiding the subs, however, I can't get jquery to show the subs on a given event: hover over "ul.menu li span"

Here's my CSS:

```
ul.menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 920px;
    background: #222;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: url(topnav_bg.gif) repeat-x;
}


ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base for sub navigation--*/
}



ul.menu li a{
    padding: 10px 5px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}



ul.menu li a:hover{
    background: url(topnav_hover.gif) no-repeat center top;
}


ul.menu li span { /*--Drop down trigger styles--*/
    width: 17px;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/bullet.png) no-repeat center top;
}




ul.menu li span{background-position: center bottom; cursor: pointer;} /*--Hover effect for trigger--*/



ul.menu li ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute; /*--Important - Keeps subnav from affecting main navigation flow--*/
    left: 0; top: 35px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;

    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
}



ul.menu li ul.menu li{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #252525; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    clear: both;
    width: 170px;
}



html ul.menu li ul.menu li a {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
    background: #333 url(dropdown_linkbg.gif) no-repeat 10px center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}



html ul.menu li ul.menu li a:hover { 
    background: #222 url(dropdown_linkbg.gif) no-repeat 10px center;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {

$('ul.menu li ul').hide();

    $("ul.menu li ul").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled (Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav*)

    $("ul.menu li span").hover(function() { //When trigger is clicked...

                                        // alert("No error!"); 

        //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
        $(this).parent().find("ul.menu li ul").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click

        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){
            $(this).parent().find("ul.menu li ul").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });

        //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
        }).hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function(){  //On Hover Out
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
    });

});
```

If i edit this line: `$(this).parent().find("ul.menu li ul").slideDown('fast').show();` to this: `("ul.menu li ul").slideDown('fast').show();` It will show ALL the submenus for all parent items - obiviously I only want to show the submenu of the parent menu that I'm hovering over.  When I try to add back in `$(this).parent()...` It won't show any subs at all.

Thank you.

Comment: You can do that with CSS: `ul#topnav > li > ul` matches a second-level `ul` inside of the original `ul`.

Comment: Definitely go with Blender's suggestion, changing this using a theme preprocess function usually involves string replacement which is never great

Comment: @Blender might as well post that as the answer. Though I think @Micheal might be looking for `$('ul#topnav > li > ul');`, so he can select the appropriate elements.

Comment: Thank you all for responding.  When I look at my main menu CSS using "inspect element" in Chrome, I see: `<div id="navigation"><div id="navigation"><ul class="links"><li class="menu-227 first active"><a href.... class = "active">Home</a>` Now under "Home" should be a sub-menu item and the ul of that sub item will need to have the class "subnav".  So using @Blender's technique I can essentially rename the "links" class to "topnav"?

Comment: For additional clarification, this is actually what I'm trying to accomplish with my Drupal menu:http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html

Comment: @Michael: Why do you have multiple tags with the same `id`? That will be hard on the parser.

Comment: @Blender There are two "navigation" id's because of the theme I'm dealing with - not something I originally coded. It has to do with a ternary operator in the theme: (psuedo code - within a div with id of "navigation") if using main-menu then class = navigation else class = superfish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.  Here's the corrected working code to get the tutorial i mentioned in my original post to work with Drupal 7:

Note: I'm using the main-menu as a block here.

CSS:

```
ul.menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 920px;
    background: #222;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: url(topnav_bg.gif) repeat-x;
    z-index:999;
}



ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base for sub navigation--*/
}



ul.menu li a{
    padding: 10px 5px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}

ul.menu li a:hover{
    background: url(topnav_hover.gif) no-repeat center top;
}


ul.menu li span { /*--Drop down trigger styles--*/
    width: 17px;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    background: url(images/bullet.png) no-repeat center top;
}


ul.menu li span{background-position: center bottom; cursor: pointer;} /*--Hover effect for trigger--*/


ul.menu li ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute; /*--Important - Keeps subnav from affecting main navigation flow--*/
    left: 0; top: 35px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    display:none;
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
}

ul.menu li ul.menu li{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #252525; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    clear: both;
    width: 170px;
}


html ul.menu li ul.menu li a {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
    background: #333 url(dropdown_linkbg.gif) no-repeat 10px center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}


html ul.menu li ul.menu li a:hover { 
    background: #222 url(dropdown_linkbg.gif) no-repeat 10px center;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {


    $("ul.menu li ul").parent().append("<span></span>"); 

    $("ul.menu li span").click(function() { //When trigger is clicked...


        //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click

        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){
            $(this).parent().find("ul").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });

        //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
        }).hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function(){  //On Hover Out
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
    });

});
```

Partial page.tpl.php:

```
<?php if ($page['navigation'] || $main_menu): ?>
      <div id="navigation"><div class="section clearfix">

        <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
          'links' => $main_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'main-menu',
            'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            'text' => t('Main menu'),
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array('element-invisible'),
          ),
        )); ?>

        <?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>

      </div></div><!-- /.section, /#navigation -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This implementation works without having to inject any additional classes into Drupal's menu HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I use the drupal menu block module and want to add to main menu item (first level) a css class for such responsive jQuery Navigation.

http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation/

```
<nav>
        <ul id="nav" role="navigation">
            <li class="top-level item-with-ul"><a href="" class="link-with-ul">Item #1</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#content">Sub 1 Item #1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub 1 Item #2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub 1 Item #3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub 1 Item #4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="top-level item-with-ul"><a href="" class="link-with-ul">Item #2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Sub 1 Item #1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub 1 Item #2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub 1 Item #3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="top-level"><a href="">Item #3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="top-level item-with-ul"><a href="" class="link-with-ul">Item #4</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Sub 1 Item #1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub 1 Item #1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub 1 Item #1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="top-level"><a href="">Item #5</a>
            </li>           
        </ul>                                           
    </nav>
```

I need the css class in the `<a href=""></a>` Link and first `<li></li>` class.

See item-with-ul and link-with-ul

Here you see my started Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what your problem is. It also seems that you are a little uncertain how css targeting works. Blender's original comment above is one way to target (though it needs to be a class not an id for the `topnav` since your html has it as a class).

```
ul.topnav > li > ul
```

This would apply styles to any second level `ul` just as Blender said. Additionally, since your second level already has a class `subnav` the same targeting can be achieved by:

```
.subnav
```

assuming the class does not show up elsewhere or by

```
.topnav .subnav
```

if it is used elsewhere besides in the `topnav` list.

However, it seems that your question may be how to target a specific `subnav` in the navigation menu. One way might be:

```
.topnav > li:hover .subnav
```

which will only activate the styles on the mouse hover over the particular `li` that the `subnav` resides in. If I can assume that your `a` tags will eventually have real hrefs, then you could also specifically target by those. For example if your Home link is `<a href="/Home.html">Home</a>` then

```
a[href^=Home.html] + ul
```

would match the `ul` that immediately follows that link (which seems to be what you mention in your comment).

Comment: Thank you Scott. As far as being unclear of what my problem is, I'm trying to take the css found [here](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html) and apply it to Drupal's main-menu. Once I do that,I can get the jQuery aspect work. So one of two things need to happen: I either need to 1) Add the css classes found in that tutorial to Drupals UL and nested UL elements in main-menu or 2) I need to rename the classes in that CSS to what ever Drupal uses in main-menu. In the meantime, I'll try your implementation.

Comment: I've gotten further and have revised my original question.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7, try placing something like this in your theme's `template.php` file:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_menu_tree().
 */
function MY_THEME_preprocess_menu_tree(&$variables) {

  // Use the devel module to inspect the theme hook suggestions
  // for your menu. For my particular theme and main menu, the
  // suggested theme hook is menu_tree__primary
  //dpm($variables);

}

/**
 * Implements theme_menu_tree__primary().
 */
function MY_THEME_menu_tree__primary($variables) {
  return '<ul class="foo bar">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

The caveat to this approach is we're hard coding the class name, so it will not allow any other module to have a say in the class names that appear here. I swear there is a way to hook into the building of the menu at a render array level, where we can easily append/remove classes to the attributes class array, but for the life of me I can't track down that approach right now.